# Erase object from vector in C++

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I am trying to erase an object from a vector in C++, but it is giving a strange (and long) error. I have written this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

class foo
{
    int a;
    public:
    foo(int _a):a(_a){}
};

int main() {
    foo f1(5),f2(10);
    vector<foo> vec = {f1,f2};
    vec.erase(remove(vec.begin(),vec.end(),f1),vec.end()); // remove f1 (error)
    return 0;
}
```

The exact error I get is [here](http://ideone.com/ffYg1J).
On the other hand, when I create a vector of int and then try to remove an integer from that vector, it works fine.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int> vec = {5,10};
    vec.erase(remove(vec.begin(),vec.end(),5),vec.end()); // works fine
    return 0;
}
```

I am not sure why there is an error in first case.

Comment: Post exact error message

Comment: There is no `foo::operator ==`

Comment: My guess you get the error because you have no comparison operator defined for the `foo` class. How will the compiler otherwise know how to compare instances of the `foo` class?

Comment: @MohitJain I have posted an ideone link now which shows the error. Thanks

Comment: The error message, tells you, **exactly**, what is wrong. Reading them, will help you a great deal, when trying to figure out why they happened.

Comment: @HappyMittal As I already said, the error tells exactly what's wrong: `error: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'foo' and 'const foo')`.

Comment: Thanks people for comments. I got my mistake.

Comment: Quick question : your sole purpose is to delete the object only??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `std::remove` your `class foo` should contain `operator ==` or you should explicitly pass a comparison function. For standard types (`int` for example), comparison function is defined by language and thus it compiles without an error.

One example for `operator ==` can be:

```
class foo
{
    ...
    bool operator ==(const foo &t) const { return t.a == a; }
};
```